# Grouping x-axis labels

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to group labels on axis to show a trend using highcharts and react.

1. First category will have workweeks
2. all workweeks will have these sub categories: testA, testB, testC, testD

all will have pass/fail count (which will goto to series)

data example:

> ww20 -> testA [pass:2,fail:3]
> testB [pass:2,fail:3]
> testA [pass:2,fail:3]
> testA [pass:2,fail:3]

> ww21 -> testA [pass:2,fail:3]
> testB [pass:2,fail:3]
> testA [pass:2,fail:3]
> testA [pass:2,fail:3]

Do we have any highchart configuration which can help me achieve this (attached image for output I need)?

Could not find any option to group x-axis categories labels
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to use [Grouped Categories](https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/) plugin.

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: [{
      name: "WW20",
      categories: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    }, {
      name: "WW21",
      categories: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    }, {
      name: "WW22",
      categories: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    }]
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lgfs2z7c/

**Docs:** https://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/